# I have Eyelid bones set up (and working) in Blender, but I can't figure out how to control the bones in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

In Blender I have a bone on each eyelid. In Blender, they make the character's eyelids move up and down, as expected.

But I can't figure out how to get that same behavior going on in Unity. When I import the FBX model into Unity (Armature included) and find an eyelid bone and move its transform, nothing happens to the character's eyelid.

Why would moving the bones in *Blender* do something, but in *Unity* nothing happens? Appreciate any help.

Also, I made sure the Rig was 'Humanoid' and that an Avatar was correctly set up, if that matters.

EDIT: The answer was that you use Pose Mode to create Blendshapes and then export the model with those Blendshapes into Unity!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that you move the bones in Pose Mode to create Blendshapes and then export the model with those Blendshapes into Unity!! :D